# How can I make the full row editable with jeditable plugin? 

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I am working in MVC & using jquery.jeditable plugin for inplace editing in grid.It allows me to perform cell edit one at a time, can you please let me know how can i make the full row editable with jeditable plugin ?

Comment: Try and accept maybe you'll like it ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#rowId td').editable("url_here", {
    onblur : 'ignore',
    event : 'make_cell_editable"
    //other options here
   });


$('#rowId').click(function (){
           $(this).each(function (){
                   $(this).trigger('make_cell_editable');
        });
});
```